# Creating multiple clickable regions of an image, when hoverover shows a dialog with info

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have screenshots of my app that I want to have animated mini overlay circles on each buttons such that when hover over, displays a small text box with some information.

I want to use it to show information of an app for our designers. For example, how many users click on a button, etc.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with a WYSWYG editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "area map" > https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_shape.asp
I don't know about WYSIWYG editors.